# Copying PDFs while keeping folder structure

Tags: powershell, copy, directory

So I am trying to copy all the folders and keep the structure that only contain pdf's. I am not sure if there is a way to do this, I have managed to get some of the script to work.

However, when I run it, it copies all the folders even if they don't have PDFs in them. Also I have noticed that my script fails to check the folder and creates in the next directory down. For example:

> C:\temp copied once shows C:\temp.
>   If I was to run the script again it now shows C:\temp\temp

Below is my Code:

```
$Criteria = *.pdf
$Trial = c:\temp\folders.txt
$Server = \\file
$Path = homedrives\home
$des = $Path
$safe = Get-Content $Trial
$safe | ForEach-Object {
    #find drive-delimeter
    $first = $_.IndexOf("\\");
    if ($first -eq 1) {
        #stripe it
        $newdes = Join-Path -Path $des -ChildPath @($_.Substring(0,1)+$_.Substring(2))[0]    
    } else {
        $newdes = Join-Path -Path $des -ChildPath $_
    }
    $err = 0
    $fr = 0
    $folder = Split-Path -Path $newdes -Parent
    #check if folder exists"
    $void = Get-Item $folder -ErrorVariable err -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($err.Count -ne 0) {
        #create when it doesn't
        $void = New-Item -Path $folder -ItemType Directory -Force
    }  
    #$void = Copy-Item -Path $_ -destination $newdes  -Force -Verbose
    $void = Copy-Item -Path $_ -destination $newdes -Filter $Criteria -Recurse -Force  -ErrorVariable fr -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $CR = "`r`n"
    $RR = $fr[0].CategoryInfo.TargetName.ToString()
   "List of PDF's that Failed To Copy" + $CR + "--------------------------------------------------------------" + $CR + $RR | Out-file -Append $Er
    Write-Host $_
}
Write-Host $newdes
```

Comment: Why not just use `robocopy`?

Comment: The files are in a archived state and using robocopy doesn't seem to bring them out of it. Using powershell seems to be the only way,

Comment: What does "files are in a archived state" mean? What does "bring them out of it" mean?

Comment: Robocopy can remove the Archive attribute from the files if you tell it to.

Comment: Archived is storing the data offsite IE Azure and called upon when accessed, I would rather not use robocopy as it seems to fail each time. do you think there is something I can do to amend my code to stop duplicating folders?

Comment: What does "it seems to fail each time" mean?

Comment: As in it duplicates the folder further down the structure for example;

1st run it creates d:\temp\temp1\temp2
2nd run it creates d:\temp\temp1\temp1\temp2
3rd run it creates d:\temp\temp1\temp1\temp2

so it looks like it checks the second time but not the first.

Also I am working with a text file that contains the source path and folder structure so I cycle through that to create a destination.

Comment: There are too many "seems to" and "looks like" in your descriptions. I recommend learning how `robocopy` works instead of trying to write this yourself. Robust file replication can be a challenging task if you are not an experienced programmer (hence our recommendations not to reinvent the wheel).

Answer (score 0):

ok, so looks like I have cracked it, for future reference, my code actually uses user input to determine locations, it then selects the criteria the user requested and then copies only files with the extensions defined. It copies the folder structure without duplicating and although the filename limitations of windows still exist, there is an error log that is produced that shows the files that have failed to copy. Thanks for all your assistance in this matter.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null -ErrorAction Stop
$Server = "\\" + [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please choose a Server to search", "Server Choice")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null -ErrorAction Stop
$Choice = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please choose a File Path to search", "File Path Choice")  + "\"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null -ErrorAction Stop
$Ext = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please choose a File type i.e. *.PST", "Location Choice") 
#$Ext.ToUpper()
$Criteria = "*." + $Ext
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null -ErrorAction Stop
#$FPath = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please choose a path to copy to", "Location Choice") 
$Path = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please choose a folder to store the data", "Path Choice") + "\"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null -ErrorAction Stop
#$Name = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please choose a filename", "File Name Choice")
$Search = $Server +"\"+ $Choice 
$FileName = $Path
$Info = $Path + "FileCopy.txt"
$Trial = $Path + "Folders.txt"
$Type = $Path + "$Ext's.txt"
$Er= $Path + "Failed Copying.txt"
$Trial2 = $Path + "Folders.txt"
#$Server2 = "\" + $Server
#$File = $Path + $Name
if( -Not (Test-Path -Path $Path ) )
{
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Path |out-null
}
Else{
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('The directory already exists','Error','Ok','Error') 
    -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
$properties = @(
    'Directory'
    ' '
    'Name'
    ' '
    @{
        Label = 'Size'
        Expression = {
            if ($_.Length -ge 1GB)
            {
                '{0:F2} GB' -f ($_.Length / 1GB)
            }
            elseif ($_.Length -ge 1MB)
            {
                '{0:F2} MB' -f ($_.Length / 1MB)
            }
            elseif ($_.Length -ge 1KB)
            {
                '{0:F2} KB' -f ($_.Length / 1KB)
            }
            else
            {
                '{0} bytes' -f $_.Length
            }
        }
        }
        $result = Get-ChildItem -Path $Search -Recurse -Include $Criteria -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  ) | Out-Null
  $Result
#Get-ChildItem -Path $Search -Recurse -Include *.pst -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
$Folders = (get-childitem -Path $Search | where-object { $_.PSIsContainer }).Count

If (Test-Path $Search) {
    <#Write-Host
    Write-Host "Listing All  Found In $Path" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    Write-Host "=========================================" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"#>

    Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms

    ## -- Create The Progress-Bar
    $ObjForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $ObjForm.Text = "Progress-Bar of searched folders"
    $ObjForm.Height = 100
    $ObjForm.Width = 500
    $ObjForm.BackColor = "White"

    $ObjForm.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
    $ObjForm.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen

    ## -- Create The Label
    $ObjLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $ObjLabel.Text = "Starting. Please wait ... "
    $ObjLabel.Left = 5
    $ObjLabel.Top = 10
    $ObjLabel.Width = 500 - 20
    $ObjLabel.Height = 15
    $ObjLabel.Font = "Tahoma"
    ## -- Add the label to the Form
    $ObjForm.Controls.Add($ObjLabel)

    $PB = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
    $PB.Name = "PowerShellProgressBar"
    $PB.Value = 0
    $PB.Style="Continuous"

    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500 - 40
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20
    $PB.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $PB.Left = 5
    $PB.Top = 40
    $ObjForm.Controls.Add($PB)

    ## -- Show the Progress-Bar and Start The PowerShell Script
    $ObjForm.Show() | Out-Null
    $ObjForm.Focus() | Out-NUll
    $ObjLabel.Text = "Starting. Please wait ... "
    $ObjForm.Refresh()

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
 Out-Null
    ## -- Execute The PowerShell Code and Update the Status of the Progress-Bar

    $result = Get-ChildItem -Path $Search -Recurse -Include $Criteria -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    $Counter = 0
    ForEach ($Item In $Result) {
        ## -- Calculate The Percentage Completed
        $Counter++
        [Int]$Percentage = ($Counter/$Result.Count)*100
        $PB.Value = $Percentage
        $ObjLabel.Text = "Scanning $Folders Folders For $Criteria in $Search"
        #$ObjLabel.Text = "Found $counter $Criteria in $Search"
        $ObjForm.Refresh()
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 150
        # -- $Item.Name
        #"`t" + $Item.Path

    }

    $ObjForm.Close()
    #Write-Host "`n"
}
Else {
    #Write-Host
    #Write-Host "`t Cannot Execute The Script." -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    #Write-Host "`t $Search Does Not Exist in the System." -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    #Write-Host
}
Out-Null
Sort-Object -Property DirectoryName |

Format-Table -Property $properties |

out-file $Info



$Search| out-file -Append $Trial 
#$Search | Out-File -Append $Trial2


$result | out-file -Append $Info

$result | Select Name | out-file -Append $Type
$CR = "`r`n"
"List of PDF's that Failed To Copy" + $CR + $CR + "--------------------------------------------------------------" | Out-file $Er
$des = $Path
#$PDFs= get-content $Type
$safe = Get-Content $Trial
#$Ten = @($Criteria)
$safe | ForEach-Object{
    #find drive-delimeter
    $first=$_.IndexOf("\\");

    if($first -eq 0){
        #stripe it
    $newdes=Join-Path -Path $des -ChildPath @($_.Substring(0,1)+$_.Substring(2))[0]    
        }
        $newdes=Join-Path -Path $des -ChildPath $_
    $err=0
    $fr=0
    $folder=Split-Path -Path $newdes -Parent
    $folders=Split-Path -Path $newdes -leaf
    #$fy = $folder + "\" +$folders
    #check if folder exists"
   $void=Get-Item $newdes -ErrorVariable err  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue #-verbose
   If(!(Test-Path -Path $newdes) ){
    $err=1
   }
     if($err.Count -ne 0){
        #create when it doesn't
        $void=New-Item -Path $folder -ItemType Directory #-verbose
        } 
            #$void=Copy-Item -Path $_ -destination $newdes  -Force -Verbose
            $void=Copy-Item -Path $_ -destination $folder -Filter $Criteria -Recurse -Container -Force -ErrorVariable fr  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -verbose
            write-host "------------------------------------------------------- Break -------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
            foreach($re in $fr){
            $RR = $re[0].CategoryInfo.TargetName.ToString()
            $X5 = $re[0].CategoryInfo.Reason.ToString()
            $X6 = $re[0].TargetObject.DirectoryName.ToString()
            $X6 + $CR + $X5 + "---" + $RR + $CR | Out-file -Append $Er
            }
    write-host "`n" $_
    }
    write-host "`n------------------------------------------------------- End of Script -------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Blue`
```